# Sorting tables in wp plugin is not working, what is missing?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, sorting

I have some code which I thought I remembered working before but I cannot remember if I tested it. I thought I did. Anyway I moved the site to a new domain today and don't ahve access to the original domain for testing.

It works fine on the first column, but if I choose any other columns, I get the error below.

> [28-Jun-2021 21:39:46 UTC] WordPress database error You have an error
> in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
> server version for the right syntax to use near 'Viewed desc LIMIT 50
> OFFSET 0' at line 1 for query SELECT * FROM wp_myrows ORDER BY Date
> Viewed desc LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0 made by
> do_action('toplevel_page_wp_list_table_class'), WP_Hook->do_action,
> WP_Hook->apply_filters, SP_Plugin->plugin_settings_page,
> Customers_List->prepare_items, Customers_List::get_customers

I should be able to click on sorting columns, but this section is where the error_log said I have an issue:

```
public static function get_rows( $per_page = 50, $page_number = 1 ) {

    global $wpdb;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}myrows";

    if ( !empty( $_REQUEST['orderby'] ) ) {
        $sql .= ' ORDER BY ' . esc_sql( $_REQUEST['orderby'] );
        $sql .= !empty( $_REQUEST['order'] ) ? ' ' . esc_sql( $_REQUEST['order'] ) : ' ASC';
    }

    $sql .= " LIMIT $per_page";
    $sql .= ' OFFSET ' . ( $page_number - 1 ) * $per_page;


    $result = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, 'ARRAY_A' );

    return $result;
}
```

I could be wrong but it looks like it's looping? I spent a lot of time on this and I can't find the error. How can I solve this problem so that the table columns can sort properly?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `order_by` parameter contains a value made of multiple words.

When your script builds the query it ends up with `SELECT * FROM wp_myrows ORDER BY Date Viewed desc LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0`. In this case `Date Viewed` is not a valid column name.

To make the query valid you would have to add backticks around the multi-word column name. So your result should be:

`` SELECT * FROM wp_myrows ORDER BY `Date Viewed` desc LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0 ``

That means your code should be something like:

```
public static function get_rows( $per_page = 50, $page_number = 1 ) {

    global $wpdb;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}myrows";

    if ( !empty( $_REQUEST['orderby'] ) ) {
        $sql .= ' ORDER BY `' . esc_sql( $_REQUEST['orderby'] ) . '`';
        $sql .= !empty( $_REQUEST['order'] ) ? ' ' . esc_sql( $_REQUEST['order'] ) : ' ASC';
    }

    $sql .= " LIMIT $per_page";
    $sql .= ' OFFSET ' . ( $page_number - 1 ) * $per_page;


    $result = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, 'ARRAY_A' );

    return $result;
}
```